# How to refer to a particular column family in put and get in rocksdb with java client?

Tags: java, rocksdb

Consider the following code

```
    try (final ColumnFamilyOptions cfOpts = new ColumnFamilyOptions().optimizeUniversalStyleCompaction()) {
        final List<ColumnFamilyDescriptor> cfDescriptors = Arrays.asList(
                new ColumnFamilyDescriptor(RocksDB.DEFAULT_COLUMN_FAMILY, cfOpts),
                new ColumnFamilyDescriptor("my-first-columnfamily".getBytes(), cfOpts)
        );

        final List<ColumnFamilyHandle> columnFamilyHandleList =
                new ArrayList<>();

        try (final DBOptions options = new DBOptions()
                .setCreateIfMissing(true)
                .setCreateMissingColumnFamilies(true);
             final RocksDB db = RocksDB.open(options,
                     "/mnt/my_db", cfDescriptors,
                     columnFamilyHandleList)) {
            try {
                // Question: How do I refer to a particular column family by name, for example my-first-columnfamily
                db.put(columnFamilyHandleList.get(0), "myKey".getBytes(), "myValue".getBytes());

            } finally {
                for (final ColumnFamilyHandle columnFamilyHandle :
                        columnFamilyHandleList) {
                    columnFamilyHandle.close();
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

In the following line

`db.put(columnFamilyHandleList.get(0), "myKey".getBytes(), "myValue".getBytes());`

I want `put` to be able to select which `column family` to `put` to, but `put` takes a `ColumnFamilyHandle` and `ColumnFamilyHandle` does not contain the descriptor name so its hard to select a put destination.

Can someone point me a direction to achieve the above?

Thanks

Comment: The C++ Struct `ColumnFamilyHandle` has a GetName() method you can use. Im not sure about java though

Comment: As of 5.14.2, rockdsb doesnt appear to support what you're looking for but you could keep a map of name to handle

Answer (score 1):

The `ColumnFamilyHandle` has a `getName` method, see [here](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/master/java/src/main/java/org/rocksdb/ColumnFamilyHandle.java#L34).

So you can create a helper method, which searches for the name in the column family handle list.

```
 public ColumnFamilyHandle getColumnFamilyHandle(byte[] name) {
    return columnFamilyHandles
        .stream()
        .filter(
            handle -> {
              try {
                return Arrays.equals(handle.getName(), name);
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
              }
            })
        .findAny()
        .orElse(null);
  }
```